# Will a router with a firewall block forwarded packets from a sub-LAN network?

Tags: ubuntu, routing, firewall, router

I have a system that looks like so:

```
+----------+     +--------+     +--------+
|          |     |        |     |        |
| Internet |<--->| Modem  |<--->| Router |
|          |     |        |     |        |
+----------+     +--------+     +--------+
                                    ^
                                    |
                                    v
                                +--------+
                                |        |
                     +--------->| Switch |<--------+-------------+........ (other Cn computers)
                     |          |        |         |             |
                     |          +--------+         |             |
                     |              ^              |             |
                     |              |              |             |
                     v              v              v             v
                 +--------+     +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
                 |        |     |        |     |        |     |        |
                 |   A    |     |   B    |     |   C1   |     |   C2   |
                 |        |     |        |     |        |     |        |
                 +--------+     +--------+     +--------+     +--------+
```

The Router has a 192.168.x.x IP address.

Computers A and B are on the same local network (192.168.x.y and 192.268.x.z).

Computers C1 to Cn are on a sub-LAN with a different IP addresses (10.x.y.z).

So I setup B in such a way that the it can talk to C1 to Cn, it also has a 10.x.y.z IP address.

I have a firewall on all the computers to make sure that unwanted traffic gets stopped. I have services which I do not want people from the outside to connect to.

A and B work great. I have full Internet access and NTP works, etc. However, C1 to Cn have a problem. They do not get any reply from the outside. If I try to ping a public IP address, I get no return at all. I can ping B without a problem, though.

I can't see anything blocked by the firewalls on B or C1 to Cn when I do a ping, check the DNS, try to connect to anything on the Internet. So I'm thinking that the Router is the culprit.

The Router is a Netgear and the firewall is up. What I don't understand is that since the packets are being forwarded by B, if B works (sees the Internet) I would think that the forwarded packets of C1 to Cn would work just like B packets. I'm a bit at a loss here.

Here are a few entries representing the forwarding rules in the `iptables`:

This is part of the `nat` setup:

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 141 packets, 9904 bytes)
    pkts    bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
     857    54781 SNAT       all  --  *      eno1    10.0.5.21            0.0.0.0/0            to:10.5.10.2
```

Here I have the `FORWARD` in the standard `filter`:

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
  pkts    bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    29     1884 bad_tcp_packets  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
     0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eno1   eno1   !10.0.5.1             10.0.5.16/28         state RELATED,ESTABLISHED tcp flags:!0x17/0x02
     0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eno1   eno1   !10.0.5.1             10.0.5.16/28         state RELATED,ESTABLISHED udp
     8      480 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eno1   eno1    10.0.5.16/28         0.0.0.0/0            tcp
    21     1404 ACCEPT     udp  --  eno1   eno1    10.0.5.16/28         0.0.0.0/0            udp
```

The flags mean `-syn` which is redundant from the state test. We're never too cautious...

Finally, in the `INPUT` chain I also have the `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` so returning packets do not get blocked:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
  pkts    bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    39     5428 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eno1   *       0.0.0.0/0            10.0.5.1             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED tcp flags:!0x17/0x02
     0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eno1   *       0.0.0.0/0            10.5.10.2            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED tcp flags:!0x17/0x02
```

I have a very similar setup on another computer and it works just fine so I'm really thinking that it is the Netgear router. Anyone would know what is necessary to make that work properly?

Comment: `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Comment: @IporSircer, yeah, that's the first thing I've done :-)

Comment: I would suggest (if the switch can do it) to configure router-on-a-stick it is simple for maintaining and configuration

Answer (score 0):

Okay! I got it to work.

So... on my other computer, the main computer (like A) is actually given a static IP address on the Internet. That means it works just like a router. In other words, anything that hits that computer has access to the Internet.

However, on that other new setup, computer A is on the LAN only, not directly on the Internet. So the `to:<ip>` needed to use that computer A address, not yet another local address which ended up to be "lost" in there.

```
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 141 packets, 9904 bytes)
    pkts    bytes target     prot opt in     out   source     destination
     857    54781 SNAT       all  --  *      eno1  10.0.5.21  0.0.0.0/0    to:10.5.10.2
                                                                              ^
                                    this had to be A's address 192.168.x.y ---+
```

That was it. Once I switched that one IP address it started to work like a charm.